# C++ Object Pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, object

I need some help here, could you tell me how I can get p2 variable content? I can get variables through t1 and p1 but I want to use p2 to get health and mana values.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Mage{
public:
    int health;
    int mana;
    Mage(int health, int mana){
        this->health = health;
        this->mana = mana;
    }
};

int main(){

    Mage t1 = Mage(1,1);
    Mage *p1 = &t1;
    Mage **p2 = &p1;

    cout << t1.health << endl;
    cout << p1->health << endl;
    cout << "how to print variable content with p2?" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how about `(*p2)->health` ?

Comment: @Beginner has the right of this, but if you find yourself wandering into pointers to pointers outside of a trivial education example, ask yourself "Why am I doing this again?" It's rare that you need more than one level of indirection, and when it crops up, a reference to the pointer (Mage * &p2) is probably a better option.

Comment: @Beginner it worked, thanks

Comment: you're welcome and godspeed for your Mages conquests :)

Comment: @user4581301 2 levels of indirection for *pointers* is rare, yes. But if for example you are iterating over a `std::vector` of `std::unique_ptr`, `(*it)->foo()` needs 2 levels of indirection, there is no other way around it.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Agreed. I could have worded that better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
cout << (*p2)->health << endl;
```

The `*` has two meanings: to declare a pointer and to dereference a pointer. But since `->` has higher precedence than `*` you need to put `*p2` into backets.

Answer (score 1):

Your example suggests that you are looking for a single operator that dereferences two times at once. There is none in C++.

Two ways to achieve what you want. The first has already been mentioned and goes

```
std::cout << (*p2)->health << std::endl;
```

The second can be found by noting that `p1->health` is equivalent to `(*p1).health`. Hence, `(*p2)->health` is equivalent to `(**p2).health`. In a row:

```
std::cout << t1.health << std::endl;
std::cout << (*p1).health << std::endl;
std::cout << (**p2).health << std::endl;
```